# Setting other properties when property is set

Tags: c#, properties

I have a class with a number of properties.

Inparticlular, 2 properties like this that are related.

```
public string FileName { get; set; }
public string Path { get; set; }
```

The FileName property is set using XmlReader, but I don't want to store the path in the xml file.

What I want to do is set the value of the FileName property and also set the Path property. I have 2 questions:

1. Is the practice of setting properties like this ok practice?
2. Are there any better ways of achieving this when mapping from the XmlReader?

Comment: If the FileName contains the full path, why not just set Path in FileName's setter? Or change Path to a get-only property that returns FileName's path?

Comment: Your question is unclear and possibly subjective. Provide more code and explain what you think is an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
private string path;

public string FileName { get; set; }
public string Path 
{
    get 
    { 
        return path; }
    set 
    { 
        path = value;
        FileName = Path.GetFileName(value);
    } 
}
```

Comment: It's the other way round - I only want to store the filename, but even so you've followed the same principle that I've adopted. Just wasn't sute whether this was considered OK or not.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach if one property can be computed from another one is to do just that: compute it whenever it is accessed. Something like:

```
public string Path { get; set; }

public string FileName
{
    get { return System.IO.Path.GetFileName(this.Path); }
}
```